# Append and escape

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I escape before appending?  The following incorrectly appends

```
'<a here."="" goes="" string"="" title="Some " href="#">Hello</a>'
```

in the code:

```
$(function(){
    var t='Some "string" goes here.';
    var jqueryObj=$('#elem');
    jqueryObj.append('<a href="#" title="'+t+'">Hello</a>');
});
```

REVISED CODE AFTER EDIT

```
var $accounts=$('#accountList');
$accounts.find('li.accountList').remove();
for (var i = 1; i < data.o.a.length; i++) {
    $accounts.append('<li class="item displayAccount">'
    +'<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="cb" name="accounts[]" value="'+i+'" />'
    +'<span class="name">'+data.o.a[i].name
      +((data.o.a[i].e.length)?' <a class="displayError" href="#" title="'+escape(mkList(data.o.a[i].e))+'">Error</a>':null)
    +'</span>'
    +'</li>');
}
if(data.o.a[0].c.length) {$accounts.append('<li class="item displayAccount"><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" value="0"><span class="name">UNASSIGNED</span></li>');}
$accounts.find('a.displayError').displayError();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd offer a different answer than Blender just in case you don't want to use that method.

```
function escapeQuotes(str){
    return str.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Will replace double quotes with `&quot;`.

Comment: As seen my the above jsfiddle, it doesn't work exactly as you indicated.  I've tried multiple iterations of something similar, but no success.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah ha!  You almost had it right, however, too many quotes.  Please update your answer so I may select.  Thanks!  function escapeQuotes(str){return str.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');}

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has a [nice syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for creating elements safely:

```
$('<a>', {
    href: '#',
    title: t,
    text: 'Hello'  // Replace `text` with `html` if you need to.
}).appendTo(jqueryObj);
```

---

Your code relies a lot on strings, so I did what I could, but it could be made prettier:

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.o.a.length; i++) {
    var $li = $('<li class="item displayAccount"></li>');
    var $input = $('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="cb" name="accounts[]" />').val(i).appendTo($li);
    var $span = $('<span class="name"></span>').appendTo($li);

    if (data.o.a[i].e.length) {
        $('<a class="displayError" href="#">Error</a>').attr('title', mkList(data.o.a[i].e)).appendTo($span);
    }

    $li.appendTo($accounts);
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  Let me play with it to see if it will work for me.  Thanks

Comment: I just edited my original post to show the actual javascript.  I am sorry, I originally thought making it simple wouldn't change the recommended approach.  I am struggling on how to apply your solution.  Again, my bad for not giving all the requirements first time.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531: See my edit. I didn't test it, but it *might* work.